# Generate release SHA1 certificate using Android studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, sha1

I'm using Android studio to help me build a release SHA1 certificate, by going over to

- Gradle settings at the top right
- Navigate upto signingReport with the gear icon
- Right clicking then running it

And it produces a debug SHA1 certificate, as you can see below (Variant):

[image]

how can I generate a release certificate using the same tool, without using the command line

Comment: changing build variant doesn't help to find release keys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select your `buildVariant` to **release** types. Then go to *Project structure -> Default config -> SigninConfig ->* and then select your release signinConfig for **Release SHA1** and debug signinConfig for **Debug SHA1**.

[image]

Comment: it still shows androidDebugKeys